# Vuetify icon size

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, stylus, vuetify.js

recently I was working on an app using Vuetify and had trouble to change the Vuetify default colors. So I finally ended with this:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/299

Which as its says, I added the following code:

```
 <style lang="stylus">
  @require '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors.styl'
  $theme := {
    primary: #009688
    accent: #FFC107
    secondary: #00796B
    info: #B2DFDB
    warning: $red.base
    error: $red.base
    success: $green.base
  }
  @require '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'
</style>
```

In **App.vue**

So when I tested changing colors in the app, it worked as expected, so far so good. Then I noticed that it changed the size of the icons, as pictured below:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JhZT.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pra9z.png)

So, my question is:

**Is there a way to solve this problem by not using CSS? If so, how? Or if there's no way, then, how should I solve it using CSS?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately in the current version (0.17.6) you will need css to create a custom icon size.

If you wanted to set a custom default size of your icons across your app you will need to target it will css.

To target icons size you can use the following:

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

> If you are using Vuetify v1.0.0-alpha.1 or later, `<v-icon>`
> component has a `size` attribute which you can use to set an exact
> size.

Comment: I'm currently using the version 0.17.6 as you mentioned, so for now, you're right, apparently the only way to solve this is by using css. Thank you very much for your answer, I was struggling with no-sense to solve this.

Answer (score 44):

You can give icon size in `px` using `size` property in `Vuetify` icons.

```html
<v-icon size="25">home</v-icon>
```

You can also use x-small, small, medium, large and x-large in v-icon tag:

```html
<v-icon small>home</v-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best kind of solution.

Answer (score 5):

here is the sample inline css from v-icon

`<v-icon style="font-size: 5px;">home</v-icon>`

here is my sample pen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdpgmY

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the codes to the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using an `<i>` tag and setting the icon classes yourself if you can. `<v-icon>` doesn't provide much advantage anyways and the v-icon class is the one that's setting a specific font-size when all you really want is font-size: inherit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the change of colors is giving you the issue with the change of icons size, but **if you don't want to set the icon size each time**, you can optionally pass in custom variables to overwrite the global defaults like this:

```
$icon-size: 20px;
```

You can find more information about this in the [Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#variable-api)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `size="x-small"` to the v-icon element.

Examples: `<v-icon icon="$vuetify" size="x-small"></v-icon>`

Documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/#usage